# SQL Database : table column has relationship to itself

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

Good day mate, I have a question here. I am trying to make a simple enrollment system, so I came up to a "subjects" table. The problem is this subject table has a prerequisite column that the value is another subject from the same table.

```
E.g
| subID    | title         | prerequisite   |
|    345   | math54        | 555            |
|    555   | physi43       | null           |
```

My question is I am doing it right? In my perspective, it's not because I can't make a foreign key at all. And to make it worst, one subject I have multiple prerequisite value

Comment: Why can't you make a foreign key?  `... FOREIGN KEY (prerequisite) REFERENCES subjects (subID)`.  It's similar to a table that represents a hierarchical structure, where a `parentId` column is used as a FK, and is reasonable as long as each subject can have at most one prerequisite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to map a 1:n relationship.  In general, you don't do this with a single column.  You would express this using a `Prerequisites` table:

```
create table prerequisites (
    prerequisites_id int, -- auto-incremented, serial, identity
    subject_id int references subjects(subject_id),
    depends_on_subject_id int references subjects(subject_id)
);
```

Because courses can change over time, prerequisites might also.  That, in turn, suggests a type-2 table, meaning that there is an effective and end date for the dependency.  However, that might be complicated for the work you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your prerequisite column is not mandatory, so have one record pointing to another record is not a problem. But if you have a 1:n relation it is better to use a secondary table with

MAIN_ID | PREREQUISITE_ID

that allows you to have multiple relations. You can use MAIN_ID as key if you can have one or none relationships and MAIN_ID+PREREQUISITE_ID if you can have more than one per ID.